# How do i check if the user input is a string or not and give an error accordingly?

Tags: java

```
    while (x == 1)
    {
          Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);  

          System.out.println("Enter Day of Sale (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, 
          etc.):");  
          dayOfWeek= scan.nextLine();  

          if (scan.hasNextInt()) {  
              System.out.println("Invalid input, try again..."); }  

      else if (scan.hasNext()) {
          break;
      }
```

Everything else in the program works fine but i can't figure out why this won't break

Comment: `scanner.nextLine` always returns a `string`. Why do you think your code should break?

Comment: For which input you are expecting it to break?

Comment: I'm new to this so i'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. I want the program to give an error if the input entered is not a string, but I want it to continue and skip over that section of code if it is. I know it's supposed to be straightfoward but for some reason I'm not getting it. I looked online and was told to use the scan.hasNextInt function so that's why I'm using it, but if I'm not using it right then I'll gladly do it another way.

Comment: @Jgat5, are you trying to do this: give error when integer input is given and when the day is given as input, loop will break?

Comment: @Shahid When the day is given as anything that's not a string, I want it to give an error, but if it's given as a string, it shouldn't even go through the loop

Answer (score 0):

From your question you expect use to type in a day of week. Let's see of this helps you
I have a list of valid inputs like 'Sunday', 'Monday' etc and checking user input against it. It will keep on giving error until user types in a valid option.

```
        int x = 1;
        List<String> validOptions = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday");
        while (x == 1) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter Day of Sale (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,  etc.):");
            String dayOfWeek = scan.nextLine();

            if (validOptions.contains(dayOfWeek)) {
                System.out.println("valid input");
                x = 0;
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }
        }
```